# Can't run PMD Apex code check using Ant and Ivy. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ant, ivy, apex, pmd

PMD 6.5.0

Need help with connecting PMD to Ant through Ivy. When I download the full package from https://pmd.github.io and just run it using Ant target everything works fine. But I don't want to add the PMD folder to the repo. So, I tried to add an Ivy dependency to the build. With JS everything works fine, but when adding an Apex dependency an error is thrown:

`build.xml:216: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apex/jorje/semantic/ast/AstNode`

**Ant's Build.xml**

```
<target name="init">
    <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" 
    classpathref="pmd.classpath"/>
</target>

<path id="pmd.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${outputdir}/lib/">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="pmd" depends="init">
    <pmd shortFilenames="true">
        <ruleset>pmdRulesets/jsCustomRuleset.xml</ruleset>
        <formatter type="text" toFile="whaaaaaaat.txt" toConsole="true"/>
        <fileset dir="src">
        </fileset>
    </pmd>
</target>
```

**Ivy's xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="com.aquivalabs.force.ant" name="antforce" rev="0.10" conf="tasks->default">
        <exclude name="ant" />
        <exclude name="ant-launcher" />
    </dependency>

    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.pmd" name="pmd-core" rev="6.5.0">
        <artifact name="pmd-core" type="jar" />
        <exclude name="pmd-core-6.5.0.pom" />
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.pmd" name="pmd-apex" rev="6.5.0">
        <artifact name="pmd-apex" type="jar" />
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.pmd" name="pmd-apex-jorje" rev="6.5.0">
    </dependency>

    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.pmd" name="pmd-javascript" rev="6.5.0">
        <artifact name="pmd-javascript" type="jar" />
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: Looks like this issue? https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1230

Comment: Right, that's mine.